# 'WeatherModel.Root' is a type which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm been trying trying to make a weather application based on a city. I created a class which can parse the json file sent by the openweathermap API. In the beginning, I ran into a problem in the viewmodel where an error about **"'WeatherModel.Root' is a type which is not valid in the given context."**

I'm a bit confused on how to get the line to work in the viewmodel inside the LoadWeather() function where I try to give the output variable the WeatherModel.Root class from the items variable but it's not working.
Here's the Viewmodel so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using FFImageLoading.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Weather_App_2
{
    public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public static (string, string, double) LoadWeather()
        {
            using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
            {
                string json = new WebClient().DownloadString("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2147714&appid=67f9bc5970b49b875ccecec84f849300units=metric&cnt=6");

                var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherModel>(json);
                WeatherModel.Root output = items.Root;

                cityName = string.Format($"{output.name}");
                country = string.Format($"{output.sys.country}");
                temp = output.main.temp - 276;

                return (cityName, country, temp);
            }
        }

        private static (string, string, double) values = LoadWeather();
        public static string cityName = values.Item1;
        public static string country = values.Item2;
        public static double temp = values.Item3;


        public string CityName
        {
            get { return cityName; }
            set
            {
                cityName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Country
        {
            get { return country; }
            set
            {
                country = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public double Temp
        {
            get { return temp; }
            set
            {
                temp = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the WeatherModel class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Weather_App_2
{
    public class WeatherModel
    {
        public class coord
        {
            public double lon { get; set; }
            public double lat { get; set; }
        }

        public class weather
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string main { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
        }

        public class main
        {
            public double temp { get; set; }
            public double temp_min {get; set;}
            public double temp_max { get; set; }
            public int pressure { get; set; }
            public int humidity { get; set; }
        }

        public class wind
        {
            public double speed { get; set; }
        }

        public class sys
        {
            public string country { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public coord coord { get; set; }
            public List<weather> weather { get; set; }
            public main main { get; set; }
            public wind wind { get; set; }
            public sys sys { get; set; }
            public string country {get; set;}
            public string name { get; set; }


        }

     }
}
```

Comment: var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherModel.Root>(json); and remove the next line. See if that works.

Comment: What do you mean by not working here?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you just copied and pasted the model object from the json to Csharp converter.

And instead of replacing your WeatherModel class contents, you just put the copied code inside it. You CANNOT write one class inside another class in any programming language.

You are supposed to rename the “Root” object to your desired model object name “WeatherModel”.

So remove the public class Root and all its contents and change WeatherModel to this:

```
    public class WeatherModel
    {
        public coord coord { get; set; }
        public List<weather> weather { get; set; }
        public main main { get; set; }
        public wind wind { get; set; }
        public sys sys { get; set; }
        public string country {get; set;}
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

And then move the other classes: coord, wind, sys, weather, main below/above the WeatherModel class in the same file. You can also create separate files for them, as long as they are within the same namespace.

Also change back the lines in the code like this one: WeatherModel.Root output = items.Root; to not have Root anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of the WeatherModel only then you can access it.

```
WeatherModel.Root output = items.Root; //your wrong code
```

replace with

```
    var output = new WeatherModel
      {
         Root = items.Root
      };
```